# Error import whitenoise

Tags: python, django, python-import, whitenoise

I'm trying to deploy my website in pythonanywhere.com following djangoGirls tutorial.

When I run my website, It give me this error:

> Error running WSGI application
>
> ImportError: No module named 'whitenoise'
>
> File "/var/www/cryptoassistant_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 7, in module>
>
> from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise

My WGSI file:

```
import os
import sys
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise

application = DjangoWhiteNoise(get_wsgi_application())

path = '/home/cryptoassistant/tfg/'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
```

and my setting.py file:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)
```

I installed whitenoise

```
$ pip install whitenoise
> Requeriment already satisfied: whitenoise in path (3.3.1)
```

What I should change?

**edit**

I installed freeze and my requirements:

```
-f /usr/share/pip-wheels
Django==1.8
freeze==1.0.10
six==1.11.0
whitenoise==3.3.1
```

Comment: Check if it already installed by :
$ pip freeze

Comment: @FadyAlfred That comand return:-f /usr/share/pip-wheels
Django==1.8
whitenoise==3.3.1 so, i use: pip install freeze and returned: -f /usr/share/pip-wheels
Django==1.8
freeze==1.0.10
six==1.11.0
whitenoise==3.3.1 and later I check if my page works and no, this still same

Comment: have you added whitenoise packega in requirements.txt file?

Comment: @SHIVAMJINDAL I edited my question whit my requirements file

Comment: Are you installing whitenoise into a virtualenv?  If so, have you specified the virtualenv path on the "Web" page inside PythonAnywhere?

Comment: Correct your import to `from whitenoise.base import WhiteNoise`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use virtual environment, check(command : pip freeze) if whitenoise is installed. If yes, you can add below details to your settings.py to work.

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
  'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
  # ...
]

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
#    '/var/www/static/',
]
```

Verify/ Update your static setttings as stated above.

Next, make sure DEBUG=True and run, the collectstatic command.

To see if any errors, run makemigrations and migrate command. You should be good